# exporting wikipedia with Python

Tags: python, mediawiki, python-requests

I am trying to export a category from Turkish wikipedia page by following http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export . Here is the code I am using;

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
from sys import version


link = "http://tr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%C3%96zel:D%C4%B1%C5%9FaAktar&action=submit"

def get(pages=[], category = False, curonly=True):
    params = {}
    if pages:
        params["pages"] = "\n".join(pages)
    if category:
        params["addcat"] = 1
        params["category"] = category

    if curonly:
        params["curonly"] = 1

    headers = {"User-Agent":"Wiki Downloader -- Python %s, contact: Yaşar Arabacı: yasar11732@gmail.com" % version}
    r = requests.post(link, headers=headers, data=params)
    return r.text

print get(category="Matematik")
```

Since I am trying to get data from Turkish wikipedia, I have used its url. Other things should be self explanatory. I am getting the form page that you can use to export data instead of the actual xml. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong here? I have also tried making a get request.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @svick I am getting the page where you can submit the form the get the data, instead of getting the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no parameter named `category`, the category name should be in the `catname` parameter.

But Special:Export was not build for bots, it was build for humans. So, if you use `catname` correctly, it will return the form again, this time with pages from the category filled in. Then you are supposed to click "Submit" again, which will return the XML you want.

I think doing this in code would be too complicated. It would be easier if you used the API instead. There are some Python libraries that can help you with that: [Pywikipediabot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikipediabot) or [wikitools](http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my original answer was horribly flawed. I misunderstood the original intent.

I did some more experimenting because I was curious. It seems that the code you have above is not necessarily incorrect, it is, in fact, that the Special Export documentation is misleading. The documentation states that using `catname` and `addcat` will add the categories to the output, but instead it only lists the pages and categories within the specified `catname` inside an html form. It seems that wikipedia actually requires that the pages that you wish download be specified explicitly. Granted, there documentation doesn't necessarily appear to be very thorough on that matter. I would suggest that you parse the page for the pages within the category and then explicitly download those pages with your script. I do see an an issue with this approach in terms of efficiency. Due to the nature of Wikipedia's data, you'll get a lot of pages which are simply category pages of other pages.

As an aside, it could possibly be faster to use the actual corpus of data from Wikipedia which is available for download.

Good luck!

Comment: But that won't return pages from the category `Matematik`, just the single page `Matematik`.